# Average the values of list of tuples which have same identifiers

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have the following list of tuples. I call the first two elements of the tuples *identifiers*.

```
mylist = [('a', 'b', 1, 2),
          ('c', 'd', 5, 6),
          ('e', 'f', 0, 3),
          ('c', 'd', 7, 8),
          ('a', 'b', 9, 4)]
```

For rows in `mylist` that have the same identifiers, I would like to take the average of the third and fourth elements across the rows with the same identifiers and create a `newlist` like the one below.

```
newlist = [('a', 'b', 5, 3),
           ('c', 'd', 6, 7),
           ('e', 'f', 0, 3)]
```

Here is my working solution. But, there should be a more efficient solution. Since I implement this in a very large list (1.6m rows), I need something better.

```
Temp = [(i[0],i[1]) for i in mylist]
Temp2 = {i: [] for i in list(set(Temp))}
Temp3 = {i: [] for i in Temp2.keys()}
for i in Temp2.keys():
    for j in mylist:
        if i == (j[0],j[1]):
            Temp2[i].append(j[2])
            Temp3[i].append(j[3])
newlist = [(i[0],i[1],np.mean(Temp2[i]),np.mean(Temp3[i])) for i in Temp2.keys()]
```

Comment: Is the order of your “identifier” important? Would (a, b, 1, 2) and (b, a, 3, 4) be grouped or treated as separate?

Comment: Yes, it is. They would be separate. Indeed, in the original data, I have four elements as the identifiers. I wanted to create a reasonable example.

Comment: You could do something with `itertools.groupby()`.  You'd have to sort it first, and provide `key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1])`.

Comment: @MartinC.Martin , can you answer, if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to your performance issue is to not loop over your list many times. Especially if it’s large.

The below will group the values by identifier and then get the means and reform the desired output

```
delimiter = "-" # choose something not in your identifier. 

grouped_data = {}
for (id1, id2, val1, val2) in mylist:
    identifier = (delimiter).join([id1, id2])
    try:
        grouped_data[identifier]["col3"].append(val1)
        grouped_data[identifier]["col4"].append(val2)
    except KeyError:
        grouped_data[identifier] = {}
        grouped_data[identifier]["col3"] = [val1]
        grouped_data[identifier]["col4"] = [val2]

output_list = []
for identifier, values in grouped_data.items():
    this_output = identifier.split(delimiter)
    this_output.append(sum(values["col3"]) / len(values["col3"]))
    this_output.append(sum(values["col4"]) / len(values["col4"]))
    output_list.append(this_output)

print(output_list)
```

Here we only loop across mylist once. We then loop across the `grouped_data` once; but that’s a much smaller list.

Comment: I implemented this and ran like the Speedy Gonzales! I thought looping was inevitable. Well, it is indeed, but not the way we were doing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Excellent. If you’re ok with adding dependencies, a pandas dataframe might give you even better results than this dictionary based approach. But adding pandas is quite an assumption to make in a SO answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can do it in a list comprehension

```
mylist = [('a', 'b', 1, 2),
          ('c', 'd', 5, 6),
          ('e', 'f', 0, 3),
          ('c', 'd', 7, 8),
          ('a', 'b', 9, 4)]

ids = [x[:2] for x in mylist]
newlist = [(*i, *[sum(x) / ids.count(i) for x in zip(*[x[2:] for x in mylist if x[:2] == i])]) for i in set(ids)]
print(newlist)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am testing it now. But, I believe a more Pythonic solution should exist.

Comment: Do you think replacing `sum(x) / ids.count(i)` with `numpy.mean(x)` would make anything faster?

Comment: Not necessarily, but it removes a large dependency. If you require it otherwise and think `.mean` is better for readability then it’s a fine method. The main performance issue is that you loop over `mylist` multiple times; and that’s a very big list (as you say)